# encode and decode base64 excpetion storing to sql server 2008 r2

Tags: java, android, sql-server-2008-r2, encode, android-image

I have an android client, I want to send image from my android to my server, i convert the image to byte array, then they byte array to base64, i send the base64 string to server, i decode it in the server then stored it in my sql server 2008 r2.

#### my problem

I can't store the string to my database then retrieve it correctly, I didn't get any exception and I get result but it seems it is the wrong result.

i conclude that by doing this.

1- i send the base64 from android to server and saved the string retrieved in a static variable.
2- i asked the server to retrive the static string, i get the image in the android back.
3- but when i asked the server to retrieve the image that i supposed i saved it in the database i got wrong image ,actullly i get result but this result can't be decoded again.

I will tell you my code for insert and retrive the image in database, pleaes tell me what am i doing wrong,

#### Stored to database

```
void uploadImage(String image) {
Connection con = Database.getConnection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        try {
            callableStatement = con
                    .prepareCall("{call insertRestaurantFoodImage(?,?)}");
            ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    stringImage.getBytes());
            callableStatement.setInt(1, ID);
            ;
            callableStatement.setBinaryStream(2, b,
                    stringImage.getBytes().length);
            callableStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**the stored procedure to insert the image is**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.insertRestaurantFoodImage
    (
    @restaurantFoodID INT,
    @image VARBINARY(MAX)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    UPDATE Food_Restaurant
    SET [image] = @image
    WHERE ID = @restaurantFoodID
END
```

#### Retrieve from database

```
Connection con = Database.getConnection();
            CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
            try {
                callableStatement = con
                        .prepareCall("{call getRestaurantFoodImage(?,?)}");
                callableStatement.setInt(1, getID());
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2,
                        java.sql.Types.VARBINARY);
                callableStatement.execute();
                byte[] bytes = callableStatement.getBytes(2);
                image = new String(bytes);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**the stored procedure to retrive from database is :**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getRestaurantFoodImage
(
    @foodRestaurantID INT,
    @image VARBINARY(MAX) OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT @image = [image]
    FROM Food_Restaurant
    WHERE ID = @foodRestaurantID
END
```

**maybe i talked too much, but in the previus question, a user told me that i have to not just put the code but i have to put my problem and what i am doing.**

for those uses who asked me about how to encode and decode in android here is it:

#### encode

```
private byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    private String getBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(bitmap),
                Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return imgString;
    }
```

#### decode

```
String retrievedBase63 = client2
                .getBaseURI("restaurantFoods/OneFood/" + 5 + "/getImage");
        //Log.d("image", image);
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(retrievedBase63, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
                decodedString.length);
```

Comment: using jdbc on android is a bad idea ... it is better to made webservice for this ...

Comment: @Selvin I used jdbc in server buddy

Comment: @Selvin I am already useing REST Jersey web service, but i didn't tell u that.

Comment: how do you convert from Bitmap to byte[] ?

Comment: that is in android, the problem is not there because as i told u at the beginneg of the question, when i send the image to android and save it in static attirbute WITHOUT saving it to my database and then retrived that static attribute to android again i can see the image and put it in imageview, so the problem is in coding and decoding

Comment: please post your code to encode/decode to Base64...

Comment: @bastos.sergio I post it.

Comment: I posted the code for encode and decode, yesterday i post a question about them and the users told me i am doing the right things

Comment: I can't see anything wrong either...  You said you were able to save the image to a static attribute. I'd suggest you save to a static attribute and to the db. That way you can compare both values saved. Finally try manually calling the url "restaurantFoods/OneFood/5/getImage" on a regular browser and see if what appears on the browser matches the saved values.

Comment: before returning from getBytesFromBitmap log result.length and compare it with byte[] decodedString.length

Comment: I did what u said, the string wihch returns is just the first 8000 chars

Comment: there is more than 10000 chars is not retrived

Comment: compare length only, instead of  return
stream.toByteArray(); do: ba = stream.toByteArray(); log ba.length; return ba;

Comment: i compared lenght, before storing to db it was 22270, after it becomse 8000

Comment: In your setter your calling `callableStatement.setInt(1, ID);`, but in your getter your calling `callableStatement.setInt(1, getID());` Are both places resolving to the same int value?

Comment: @bastos.sergio yes of couse they are the same, however, i replace getID with ID and still the same problem, but look is it possible that sql server 2008 just retrived (or stored) 8000 for varbinary type?

Comment: after calling byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(retrievedBase63, Base64.DEFAULT);

decodedString.length becomes 8000? strange...

Comment: @pskink no no , u r talking in mobile, i am talking in server, after retriveing the data from db , it becomes 8000, before storing it, it was 22270

Comment: how are you getting the 8000 characters number? You should know that Management Studio by default only displays 8000 characters per column...

Comment: @smolina before you call BitmapFactory.
decodeByteArray what is the length of byte[]
decodedString ?

Comment: I found someting might be intresting, look at the getimage function, at the end, i make image = new String(bytes); maybe this is not the right way to make the bytes to base64?

Comment: @pskink wait please i will check

Comment: i put this `Log.d("SIISIISIIS", decodedString.length+"" );`, the answer was 6000

Comment: it soooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooolved, i had to used longvarbianry not varbinary, thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaks to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981631/jdbc-stored-png-image-at-sql-server-2008-r2-gives-not-complete-data?noredirect=1#comment24532351_16981631

Comment: You're right, change `image = new String(bytes);` to `image = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);`

Comment: ok so your problem is defintely on the server side, but its a black magic to me so cannot help more, sorry

Comment: yes i have to change the `image = new String(bytes)` but when i typed Base64, millions of classes i found , which one is the best please

Comment: @pskink problem solved, it was because i am suing varbinary not longvarbinary

Comment: @SmolinaFezaphitsh do u have any idea of converting the image stored in sql server 2008 r2 into android bitmap? i afraid image stored in Database is not Base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I also commented (and responded) on [jdbc stored png image at sql server 2008 r2 gives not complete data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981631/jdbc-stored-png-image-at-sql-server-2008-r2-gives-not-complete-data) older version of SQL Server had a limit of 8kb for `varbinary` and `varchar`. Either the driver simply doesn't support longer for `getBytes` or `getString`, or you might be using an older JDBC driver. Another possibility is that you need to register the OUT parameter as `java.sql.types.LONGVARBINARY` (or `LONGVARCHAR`).

In any case (also in the other question), I am wondering why you are first encoding in base64 before storing your data. Just store the raw bytes in a `VARBINARY`.