# jdbc stored png image at sql server 2008 r2 gives not complete data

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to save base64 image to my SQL Server 2008 R2, I used this:

```
Connection con = Database.getConnection();
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

try
{
    callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{call insertRestaurantFoodImage2(?,?)}");
    callableStatement.setInt(1, ID);
    
    callableStatement.setString(2, stringImage);
    callableStatement.executeUpdate();
} 
catch (SQLException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The stored procedure to save the string is :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.insertRestaurantFoodImage2
    (@restaurantFoodID INT,
     @image VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE Food_Restaurant
    SET [image] = @image
    WHERE ID = @restaurantFoodID
END
```

Retrieve data like this:

```
Connection con = Database.getConnection();
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

try 
{
    callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{call getRestaurantFoodImage2(?,?)}");
    callableStatement.setInt(1, getID());
    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    callableStatement.execute();

    image = callableStatement.getString(2);
} 
catch (SQLException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The stored procedure to get image is :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.insertRestaurantFoodImage2
    (@restaurantFoodID INT,
     @image VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE Food_Restaurant
    SET [image] = @image
    WHERE ID = @restaurantFoodID
END
```

When I check the string before insert it and after retrieve it, the result was not equal, the retrieved image has about the first 500 (less or more) chars.

What am I doing wrong please?

I know u will tell me, try to use varbinary instead of varchar, so please look at this question, I tried and had problems [encode and decode base64 excpetion storing to sql server 2008 r2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980675/encode-and-decode-base64-excpetion-storing-to-sql-server-2008-r2)

Please help

Comment: An image is not string data, use `VARBINARY` instead.

Comment: I tried as i told u in the question ,i have this problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980675/encode-and-decode-base64-excpetion-storing-to-sql-server-2008-r2 the data retrieved is 8000 lenght, the data send is 22270 length

Comment: In the other question you are also using `String` for your imagedata which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Problem might also be related to a limit of 8000 for `VARBINARY`. You might need to use one of the stream methods to get the value, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378813%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes in the previeous quesrtion i see that i returning string not base64, not even when i used appache deconde and encode, still the same results, do u mean that varbinarry just use 8000 ?

Comment: Older version of SQL Server had a limit of 8kb for varbinary and varchar. Either the driver simply doesn't support longer for `getBytes` or `getString`, or you might be using an older JDBC driver. That is why I suggest you use one of the stream methods (eg `getBinaryStream()`).

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaak youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu, the solve is to put longvarbianry not binary, i looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooove youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I also commented older version of SQL Server had a limit of 8kb for `varbinary` and `varchar`. Either the driver simply doesn't support longer for `getBytes` or `getString`, or you might be using an older JDBC driver. Another possibility is that you need to register the OUT parameter as `java.sql.types.LONGVARBINARY` (or `LONGVARCHAR`).

In any case (also in the other question), I am wondering why you are first encoding in base64 before storing your data. Just store the raw bytes in a `VARBINARY`.